# Positive term for "unnegated"?

Tags: terminology, logic

I read a paper which talks about "a logic formula in which each variable appears at most twice unnegated and once negated". The term "unnegated" is double-negative, which makes it slightly unclear. Is there a more positive term to denote a variable that is not negated?

I looked in an [English thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/negate), but all suggestions seem out-of-context in logic.

Comment: "... appears at most twice positively (as a positive literal) and once negatively (as a negative literal)." The parenthetical explanations are optional.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks! I used your suggestion in the following Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#NP-complete_when_some_groups_contain_3_or_more_intervals

Comment: I wouldn't consider the term "unnegated" to be a double negative, since the "un-" prefix applies to the variable *itself* while the "-negated" stem applies to the truth or falsity *represented by that variable*.  Other possibilities would be "true form" and either "complemented form" or "negated form".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rephrase your statement as "a logic formula in which each variable appears at most twice positively and once negatively". This relies on the common usage of positive and negative *literals*.

Answer (score 6):

You often see negative variables ($\neg x$) and positive variables ($x$). A [literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28mathematical_logic%29) is either a positive or a negative variable.